# How do I apply git changes from master to different branch?

Tags: git

I have 3 branches:

- master
- test1
- test2

Now I did add some changes to master.

Task is: apply these changes to test1 and test2, but save these branches separated from master.

It looks simple, but I can't manage with that.

Now, I'm trying merge test1 with master:

```
git checkout test1
git merge master # already up-to-date
git pull origin master # up-to-date
git push origin test1 # Everything up-to-date
```

No changes from master in result.

Trying rebase:

```
git checkout test1
git rebase master
git status

On branch test1
Your branch and 'origin/test1' have diverged,
and have 1 and 7 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

git pull
```

> Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
>   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/test1' by 2 commits.

What is these 2 commits? I have a lot of commits in master.

Also there is still no changes from master in current branch.

So I can only revert these with

So, how can I apply latest commits from master properly?

```
git reset --hard origin/test1
```

Comment: Typically, there are two options:

 1. Merge master into test1/test2
 2. Rebase onto master

Apparently did you try already both of these and it didn't work. Please explain what exactly is the outcome for both of there options. It always helps to look at the log/graph with `git log --decorate --graph --oneline --all`.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this behavior. Steps: create master, commit. Create test1, commit. Checkout master, divergent commit. Checkout test1, merge, resolve conflicts... no issues?

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring changes from other branches keeping them "separate" (as if they had been developed independently on separate branches) I think you should try **git cherry-pick**. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick